# How to detect TEXT in an image more than 50words?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

according to AWS Rekognition Terms:

> A word is one or more ISO basic latin script characters that are not
>   separated by spaces. DetectText can detect up to 50 words in an image.

How can I detect text in an image it has more than 50words?

Give me a clue... thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend the use of Amazon Textract - I know this answer is long overdue and Textract didn't exist when the question was initially asked. However, I thought to provide it for the sake of people that might still want to use Rekognition for the same purpose and are facing the issue documented here .

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've wrote it down.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your image into smaller pieces, feed each one to Rekognition, then combine them at the end.